# Why is a 4mb transparent PNG taking 10-20 seconds to load as a repeated CSS background texture?

Tags: css, image, png

I have a large 4mb transparent PNG that is used as a CSS background texture like this:

```
.texture {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200vh;
}

.texture:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: url(texture.png);
  background-size: 1024px;
  background-repeat: repeat;
  -webkit-mask-image: linear-gradient(transparent 0%, #fff 10%, #fff 90%, transparent 100%);
  mask-image: linear-gradient(transparent 0%, #fff 10%, #fff 90%, transparent 100%);
}
```

The question is why is it taking like 10 to 20 seconds for it to render (even after the PNG has loaded)? So what I do is I first load all the PNGs in my application, then once they are loaded, I turn on visibility. So I know that it's not because the PNG is still downloading. The PNG has fully downloaded, and then it still takes 10-20 seconds for it to render. Why is this happening? How do I fix it?

Comment: Could it have to do with the size in this case? Maybe going through https://tinypng.com can make some difference

Comment: Painting an image is not only a network request, it also has to parse the data, unpack it, convert it to bitmap and then paint it. All this can take quite a long time. However, a 4MB png should be handled in less than 20s. Of course, your masks means that it has to be painted at least twice per frame, but still, 20s is a lot. Can you try to set up a live demo? When I tried, I couldn't reproduce: https://jsfiddle.net/3tdyacm6/